# Clear TextField using Button (Java)

Tags: java, text, textbox, swt

I'm trying to clear two text boxes using the following code.  It executes without error but the numbers entered in the text box do not change once the button is clicked.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance! :)

```
btnClear = new Button(shlTestProject, SWT.NONE);
btnClear.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        textBox1.setText("");
        textBox2.setText("");
    }
});
btnClear.setBounds(240, 298, 75, 25);
btnClear.setText("Clear");



    textBox1= new Text(shlTestProject, SWT.BORDER);
    textBox1.setBounds(224, 386, 76, 21);
    textBox1.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
            e.doit = false; //assume we don't allow it
            char myChar = e.character; // get the character typed
           if (Character.isDigit(myChar)) e.doit = true; // allow 0-9 
          if (myChar == '\b') { //allow backspace
          e.doit = true;
          }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Selection Listener to deal with with the button being pressed:

```
btnClear.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
      textBox1.setText("");
      textBox2.setText("");
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 very much!  It wasn't working at first, but I realized it was conflicting with a verifyListener I had so they could only enter numbers.  I'll try to work around that.  Thanks again.

Comment: How are textBox1/2 created?

Comment: I don't know how to add here in the comments so I appended the code to my original question.  Do you know how to specifically create an exception to allow the button to reset the text to blank while keeping the characters to 0-9?

Comment: I was able to fix this by using some code I found here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Verifyinputonlyallowdigits.htm  Thank you for your time greg-449, it means a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
        textView.setText("");

    }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

As Alexander mentioned, implement Action Listener into your class, then simply listen if the specific button was pressed. If it was, use this code to clear the text field. `TextFieldName.setText("");`.

Remember, you need to trigger your action listener event by using this line of code, else it won't work. `buttonName.addActionListener(this)`

Have fun programming!

Comment: The question is about SWT not Swing / AWT.